# Why can't 3.4 be fully represented in a `double` datatype?

Tags: c++

This is astounding that this happens and I don't have an explanation. A simple console application as created by visual studio:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ConsoleApplication.h"

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    double a;
    a = 3.4;

    return 0; // <=======  Debug break point set here
}
```

The value of `a` is 3.3999999999999999 instead of 3.4. To most programmers this isn't an issue, but why can't the number 3.4 be stored exactly as a double? Thinking about the binary it doesn't make sense.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Well there's no appropriate dupe available on SO, but you should get off with all the information [applied here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: If you want exact, look for a fixed-point number class.

Comment: I understand numerical precision (I think). As an engineer I deal with it regularly. I just don't understand why 34 * 10^-1 can't be represented by the float format exactly. I'm not doing any floating point operations here or stretching the precision to the limit.

Comment: duplicate of oh so many questions... (just trying to find one that specifically refers to C++ instead of just IEEE 754)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So to represent 0.4 in a binary representation, you look down fractions of powers of two.

Initially, you say,

```
    1/2 = 0.5.   Too big.         -> 0/2
    1/4 = 0.25.  Great.           -> 0/2 + 1/4       => 0.25
    1/8 = 0.125. We can add this. -> 0/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 => 0.375.
```

This continues (1/16, 1/32 are too large to add, but 1/64 is good), and we get the repeating pattern (in binary representation of summed fractions)

```
0.011001100110011001100....
```

Which increasingly approximates 0.4, but never quite reaches it.

See [this python link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for more simple explanation or examples.

Link to wikipedia page on [IEEE Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Highlight (float/double are base/radix 2):

> Finite numbers, which may be either base 2 (binary) or base 10 (decimal). Each finite number is described by three integers:
>
> s = a sign (zero or one),
>
> c = a significand (or 'coefficient'),
>
> q = an exponent.
>
> The numerical value of a finite number is
>
> (−1)^s × c × b^q
>
> where b is the base (2 or 10), also called radix.
> For example, if the base is 10, the sign is 1 (indicating negative), the significand is 12345, and the exponent is −3, then the value of the number is −12.345.

Link to [IEEE standard](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=4610933)

Comment: the problem is not the 0.4 per se, since floating point knows nothing about decimal and there will be other numbers ending in 0.4 that _are_ exactly representible.  The problem is that there's no possible value of `mantissa * pow(2.0, exponent)` that equals 3.4

Comment: Ah. I had no idea that a double was base 2. I thought it was `mantissa * pow(10.0, exponent)`. That explains it then.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer but it seems that a lot of documentation about IEEE floating point formats hides the fact that is it base 2. I know the mantissa and exponent are just integers, but the 2.0 is never written.

Comment: Almost every typical **binary** representation in base 2.. Or 4, 8, 16 (common), etc. It's quite hard to operate in bases other than 2^N when your most-low-level-datatype is a bit with values 0-or-1

Comment: Binary doesn't necessitate base 2... Just saying. Math...

Comment: I want to be nice, but if you google "binary", you'll probably find that's not true :)

Comment: @RussellTrahan it's more kinda _log base 2_, not _base 2_.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I never made the distinction between binary64 (usually called double) and decimal 64 as being base 2 vs 10. I've used them both a lot but never realized the base was different. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's no exact representation of 3.4 in the IEEE 754 format that uses expressions in the form `mantissa * pow(2.0, exponent)`.

The 0.4 itself isn't strictly the problem, since it's the entire number when expressed in powers of two that needs to be representable, not just the part after the "decimal" point.